# SimpleSAMLphp Stay Logged In

Tags: php, cookies, saml-2.0

I am confused regarding the cookie settings in config.php.

I have one identity provider and three service providers. I want my users to be able to stay logged in when they revisit the site within x number of days. I've set `session.cookie.lifetime` to be 7 days (60*60*24*30)

And `session.duration` is set to the default 8 hours (60*60*8).

How do I use the cookie to automatically log the user back in if it has not expired? The session duration seems to be taking precedence over the cookie lifetime.

Comment: Best place to ask this is https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/simplesamlphp

Answer (score 3):

The cookie is validated using the session data, so both `session.duration` and `session.cookie.lifetime` must be at least seven days in your case. The cookie is worthless when the session is expired, since the server won't recognise it.

It is generally a good idea choose `session.duration` a little larger than `session.cookie.lifetime` to allow for clock skew.